# Neuroevolution library/framework with GPU CUDA support

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, genetic-algorithms

I'm looking for working library/framework allowing you to use neuroevolution algorithms like [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies) with GPU support (CUDA). Are there any working libraries? I know about [AccNEAT](https://github.com/sean-dougherty/accneat) library but I couldn't get it to work with CUDA according to README, probably it's not possible. Any others?

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites generally won't do searches for best choices of technology. Perhaps you could explain what you tried with AccNEAT and what went wrong (although we may not have many experts with it here, so cannot promise that will increase your chances of an answer)? Have you tried the non-accelerated version to confirm whether your problem is with changes in the accelerated version or just using NEAT in general?

Comment: I tried the CPU version and it's working fine. I'm unable to compile it with GPU support, and I have created issue on that here: https://github.com/sean-dougherty/accneat/issues/6 
Also, I'm not talking about 'best choice' but 'any' choice with GPU support.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. Generally Stack Exchange sites won't do searches for technology fixes or libraries for answers - essentially links with "try this one". Instead it is preferred that you outline a problem, show where you are stuck in detail, and leave it more open what the suggested fix might be. Your issue ticket probably might need more detail too - although actually the developer was last active in 2015, so probably not worth investing much time there.